# MySQL & POLYGON

Tags: mysql, polygon

I'm trying add 2 polygons in MySQL database. The first polygon has a hole and the second polygon does not have a hole, like this

[Example of my polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAA29.jpg)

I have tried this statement :

```sql
INSERT INTO `zone_d2_test` (`polygon`, `boundary`) 
VALUES ('2', ST_MultiPolygonFromText('MULTIPOLYGON((
(
0 0,
0 10,
10 10,
10 0,
0 0
)
,(
2 2,
8 2,
8 8,
2 8,
2 2
)),(
(
20 0,
20 10,
30 10,
30 0,
20 0
)
))'));
```

and I got the error message : #1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Some ideas to insert those 2 polygons, which is only 1 polygon in fact ?

Comment: After running : "ALTER TABLE `zone_d2_test` CHANGE `boundary` `boundary` MULTIPOLYGON NOT NULL;" it's works !!!!   The definition of the field `boundary` was set POLYGON

Comment: Remember to post the table structure with the types when you pose a question. Happy to hear that it works and good luck!

Comment: I will try to be more precise the next time... Thank you, @lemon